# Android: How to notify Init process from native service about success/fail startup?

Tags: android

How can I notify Init process from my native service about success/fail startup?

Init process should know about this to decide whether it can start next service or not.

I heard that it can be done somehow via some properties and Android API functions. The servise is designed via C++.

Comment: Why not just a simple callback?

Comment: But my service and init process work in different processes and I cannot use callback functions. As far as I understand I need to use some API functions to pass to other process (i.e. to init process) specific parameters.

Comment: A [broadcast](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts)?